# How to compress thumbnails instead of cropping

Tags: images

I have a console script which imports woocommerce products and creates images and its thumbnails for products.

The problem is that thumbnails are cropped. And I need to compress all generated thumbnails to keep original image.

Function to put an image to DB and server:

```
private function generateFeaturedImage($imageUrl, $postId, $isCategory = false)
    {

        $imageUrl   = $this->escapefileUrl($imageUrl);
        $imageUrl   = str_replace("%26", "&", $imageUrl);
        $uploadDir  = wp_upload_dir();
        $filename   = str_replace("%20", "-", basename($imageUrl));


        if(wp_mkdir_p($uploadDir['path'])) {
            $file = $uploadDir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
        } else {
            $file = $uploadDir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
        }
        file_put_contents($file, file_get_contents($imageUrl));

        $fileType = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
        $attachment = array(
            'post_mime_type' => $fileType['type'],
            'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );
        $attachId = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $postId );
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
        $attachData = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachId, $file );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachId, $attachData );

        set_post_thumbnail( $postId, $attachId );

    }
```

Comment: You can uncheck  `Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions` in `settings > media`. Which should keep the original aspect ratio of the image. Or you'd better consider adding custom image size see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

Answer (score 0):

1) check your options_table for *_crop values. If we talking about standard wp thumbnails search for `thumbnail_crop`. Delete or change the value to 0 when find it.

2) Test.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working, it's still cropping the images